# Ms access Select query with limit options

Tags: ms-access

i have a query like : select id, name from table_name where id is not null limit 10, 20 for mysql; how can i get 10 to 20 records from table in ms access?  i know there is no limit keyword and how do i use TOP keyword?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 11 *  FROM 
        (SELECT TOP 20 * FROM table_name ORDER BY 1) 
    ORDER BY 1 DESC)
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: running this query i got error : "The select statement use reserved word"

Comment: You need to select something e.g. ...(select top 11 * from (select top 20 * from ...

Comment: No Peter. I have 1 to 50 records in my table. i want only 10 records from table. record track 20 to 30 records (like limit 20,30)

Comment: A few field names, or if you must, asterisks, need to be added to  the inner statements : `SELECT TOP 11 *`

Comment: Sorry guys, just missing the * or field names. Thanks

Comment: Can I resolve to single columns query? For example my query is - SELECT CompanyName FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 11 CompanyName  FROM 
        (SELECT TOP 20 CompanyName FROM Employees ORDER BY 1) 
    ORDER BY 1 DESC)
ORDER BY 1 , In query "1" number column index or PK ? Now I write type here : SELECT CompanyName FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 11 CompanyName  FROM 
        (SELECT TOP 20 CompanyName FROM Employees ORDER BY CompanyName) 
    ORDER BY 1 CompanyName)
ORDER BY CompanyName correct this query? -------- Thx for answ ------

Comment: This Answer don't work in my Single query! And I now try this blog - http://www.jertix.org/en/blog/programming/implementation-of-sql-pagination-with-ms-access.html